How to access Kubernetes Dashboard from outside the cluster (VirtualBox host )?
I have Kubernetes provisioned in my vagrant build using virtualbox.
I have set the port forwarding in the vagrantfile as shown below:
  ...  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 4443, host: 8444, id: 'awx_https'
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8090, host: 8090, id: 'awx_http'
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8443, host: 8443, id: 'kdashboard_console_https'
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8001, host: 8081, id: 'kdashboard_console_http'

Here is the kubernetes setup successfully deployed during provisioning:
==== Install the kubernetes Dashboard
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.7.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml

Endpoints:
# kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get endpoints -o wide
NAME                        ENDPOINTS              AGE
dashboard-metrics-scraper   192.168.102.131:8000   16h
kubernetes-dashboard        192.168.102.134:8443   16h

pods:
[root@localhost ~]# kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get pods -o wide
NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP                NODE                    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
dashboard-metrics-scraper-5657497c4c-t5zz4   1/1     Running   0          16h   192.168.102.131   localhost.localdomain   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard-78f87ddfc-nbjwc         1/1     Running   0          16h   192.168.102.134   localhost.localdomain   <none>           <none>

Service:
[root@localhost ~]# kubectl get svc -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.108.36.241   <none>        8000/TCP   17h
kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.96.123.89    <none>        443/TCP    17h
Service manifest
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard

I tried both proxy and port-forwarding and it didn't work:
1. Proxy : I tried with different ports (8001/443)
kubectl proxy
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
HTTP URL: http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
http://localhost:8090/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
test from the Vbox host:
Behavior : No Access ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
2. Port forwarding:
# Listen on port 8443 on all addresses, forwarding to 443 in the pod
kubectl port-forward -n kubernetes-dashboard service/kubernetes-dashboard 8443:443 
--address="0.0.0.0" &

test from the Vbox host:
https://localhost:8443

Behavior : No Access ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
What am I missing?
